# GET and POST values in the same link

Tags: html, post, get

I want something like this:

```
<a href="http://localhost/index.php?get=abc&post=cde&post=efg">link</a>
```

GET and 2x POST in hyperlink. How can I do that? Nothing wants to work

I have a GET array in PHP and I want to generate a link which leads to the correct url to give me those GET variables.

Comment: I dont think this can be done. A form cannot output both POST and GET

Comment: What do you mean "nothing" wants to work?  That's a valid URL.  However, if you intend on using the POST HTTP method to submit it, you will need to do it via a form.

I do not know the strict validity of submitting GET-style values in the URL with a POST request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have 2 GET variables with the same name. You can arrange them into an array as follows:

```
<a href="http://localhost/index.php?get=abc&post[]=cde&post[]=efg">link</a>
```

Just for clarification, this is still a **GET** request, links cannot normally produce a **POST** request, nor you should try to achieve that not-normally.

EDIT: To answer OP's calrification.

If you have a `$_GET` array, and you want to generate a link to get you there, you can use **[`http_build_query()`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)**

Comment: Well, I want something like this: 

<a href="http://localhost/index.php?mode=1&post1=post&post2='.$kordyarray[0].'&post3='.$kordyarray[1].'">'.$kordyarray[0].':'.$kordyarray[1].'</a>

This can be done in CURL, but I want a href link like this, to send it with my browser, not my server

Comment: I just pasted this link to show the example of what I'm trying to do, I have this from Live HTTP headers

Comment: @MichaKról: Than I don't understand **what** you want.

Comment: Well, In LIVE HTTP HEADERS I have something like this:
http://localhost/index.php?mode=1
Right?
And this is what is being sent in POST to this link:
post1=v&post2=v2&post3=v3

And I want to go to this page by clicking a link.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you understand what GET and POST means in the HTTP world.  Any items you put on a query string of a URL are GET parameters, you can't have 2 with the same name.  POST parameters are sent as a part of the request, not as a query string on the URL.

Comment: The same name was just because this is an example, I want to send POST in link, but I can only send GET. So how can I send POST in a link?

Answer (score 0):

GET and POST are http operations.

Sending values by using the ? as a separator in the url is different but related. eg:

```
foo.com/page.php?val1=1&val2=2
```

The values are called [Query String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) values.

For GET operations, values are sent as a query string values. For POST operations, the values are sent in the *body* of the POST request. This is why POST *must* be used when a lot of data is being sent to the server. (Query strings have a maximum length, HTTP requests do not.)

You **can** do a POST operation to a url that includes query string values. This is more common with Ajax requests but can be done in a form as well. Just set the `action` url to something like `index.php?val1=1&val2=2` the form's (additional) values will be sent as the http body. Remember to set `method="post"` in the form.

Note that you will need to create the query string yourself in this example, including escaping it properly.

**Repeating value names in the query string values**

Usually this causes both values to be sent, but the server overwrites the variable and ends up only presenting the last one to the client software.

So if you use a url such as

```
<a href="http://localhost/index.php?get=abc&post=cde&post=efg">
```

// It will be decoded by php and most server-side frameworks as

set *get* to abc

set *post* to cde

set *post* to efg

Result: 2 variables, *get* and *post*

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the HTTP standard that says you can't send two query string params with the same name. However, you won't be able to use $_GET to retrieve these values; $_GET will pick up the last one.  Instead, you'll have to manually parse $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].  It's not that hard and I've done it a number of times when PHP has to handle a URL pattern generated by a third-party tool.  If you're feeling really fancy you can have your query-string parse routine generate a $_GET member as an array if more than one instance of that member is encountered.